# How to extract audio from recorded video?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avassetexportsession

I have recorded video ,

I want to extract audio (.mp3 or some other file) file from recorded video file,
in iOS,

That is i need to separate audio from video.

Is it possible ? How can I achieve this ? Any library for that ?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the documentation for [AVAssetExportSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html), as well as the [transcoding example in the AVFoundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Additionally, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936464/ios-extracting-audio-from-mov-file) may be of help.