# Xcode: How to convert MP4-File to Audio-File

Tags: ios, xcode, file, audio

I want to convert a MP4-file from the apps Document folder into an Audio-file (mp3 or m4a).
I already tried, but i can not play the converted MP3-file with AVPlayer.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)convertMP4toMP3withFile:(NSString*)dstPath
{
    NSURL *dstURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dstPath];

AVMutableComposition*   newAudioAsset = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack*  dstCompositionTrack;
dstCompositionTrack = [newAudioAsset addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

AVAsset*    srcAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:dstURL options:nil];
AVAssetTrack*   srcTrack = [[srcAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];


CMTimeRange timeRange = srcTrack.timeRange;

NSError*    error;

if(NO == [dstCompositionTrack insertTimeRange:timeRange ofTrack:srcTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"track insert failed: %@\n", error);
    return;
}


AVAssetExportSession*   exportSesh = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:newAudioAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];

exportSesh.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
exportSesh.outputURL = dstURL;

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:dstURL error:nil];

[exportSesh exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    AVAssetExportSessionStatus  status = exportSesh.status;
    NSLog(@"exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler: %i\n", status);

    if(AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == status) {
        NSLog(@"FAILURE: %@\n", exportSesh.error);
    } else if(AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == status) {
        NSLog(@"SUCCESS!\n");


        NSError *error;
        //append the name of the file in jpg form

        //check if the file exists (completely unnecessary).
        NSString *onlyPath = [dstPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
        NSString *toPathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/testfile.m4a", onlyPath];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:dstPath toPath:toPathString error:&error];
        [self loadFiles];
    }
}];
}
```

Has anyone a solution for my problem or can improve my code?

Comment: You can't make an MP3 file with iOS built-in libraries. Concentrate on AAC.

Comment: @matt i have m4a after recording .i need to convert to mp3, can you give some idea

Comment: @niklasbr Hello you have already done to convert m4a file?

Answer (score 1):

replace this line:

```
exportSesh.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
```

with:

```
exportSesh.outputFileType = AVFileTypeCoreAudioFormat;
```

& this:

```
NSString *toPathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/testfile.m4a", onlyPath];
```

with:

```
NSString *toPathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/testfile.mp3", onlyPath];
```

Worked for me :)

Comment: Doing this way I receive AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed.

Comment: I tried this and my app crashes. I get the following error: ```Invalid output file type```.

Answer (score 0):

The code does work on converting mp4 to m4a. Maybe your play audio file code is wrong. Following questions may be helpful to you.

[No sound coming from AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887132/no-sound-coming-from-avplayer)

[iOS Extracting Audio from .mov file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936464/ios-extracting-audio-from-mov-file)